# How can I speed up ftp upload for android?

Tags: android

I have a android app. 
FTP upload was happening quickly but when the target version (old version 26) increased to 28, there was excessive slowdown in android 5.0 and 6.0 Sometimes, the photo uploads do not come to ftp and remain at 0 kb.
What can I do to fix this

**My Code:**

```
        boolean status = false;
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
            try {
                client.connect(FTP_HOST, 21);

                client.login(ftpUserName, ftpPassword);
                client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                client.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpDirectory + "/");

                for (String filePath :
                        fileNameList) {
                    File file = new File(filePath);

                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                    client.storeFile(file.getName(), in);
                    in.close();
                }

                status = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    client.logout();
                    client.disconnect();

                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Could it be, that this is happening, because you're not closing the connection? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323838/java-file-uploading-painfully-slow

Comment: fast on phones with android 8 version. does this make a difference between versions

Comment: Didi zou trz closing the connection on file uploaded? Is there a difference in the hardware of the phones, i.e. RAM, CPU?

Comment: There is such a problem for users using old phones. Ram from, etc. may be caused by the problem. I'll try. Thank you 
Should it be like this: for (String filePath :
                        fileNameList) {
                    File file = new File(filePath);

                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                    client.storeFile(file.getName(), in);
                    in.close();
                }
                client.disconnect();
                status = true;

Comment: Yes, the `client.disconnect()` is, I think, important here.